# Analytical formula of the elements of the inverse of a matrix plus another matrix.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse, covariance, fisher-information

I have 2 Fisher information matrices A and B. I have analytical formula of elements of matrix B (let's say B_ij).

Now, I would like to find an expression of elements (k,l) of the inverse matrix (A+B)^-1, i.e the elements ((A+B)^-1)_kl. The dual space corresponds to the covariance matrix.

The fisher information matrix A is known numerically.

Do you think it is possible ?

ps : the elements that could interest me the most should be the (k,l)=(i,j) elemements where (i,j) are the analytical terms that I know on matrix B.

Comment: Do you know wether the resulting matrix $A+B$ is even invertible?

Comment: @Sven-OleBehrend . yes, the sum $A+B$ is invertible

Comment: You could use some formula like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix, but there might be numerical instabilities occurring. I do not know enough about fisher matrices in particular to suggest a better approach.

Comment: @castor891 You should mention for those not familiar with Fisher information matrices that $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite